# laravel new many to many relation with pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table

Hi i have a table with many to many relation.

**hubs**

```
id  |  name
```

**country_hub**

```
hub_id  |  country_id
```

**countries**

```
id  |  name
```

and another table

**categories**

```
id  |  name
```

Categories belongs to combination of `hub_id` and `country_id` which is again a many to many relation to pivot table `country_hub` *eg*

```
country_hub_id |  category_id
```

Please can anybody suggest me how do i manage this. Should i make another pivot table `category_country_hub` and how do i implement it in Laravel?

which one is good approach

**category_country_hub**

```
country_hub_id | category_id
```

OR

**category_country_hub**

```
hub_id  |  country_id | category_id
```

Comment: why is this question downgraded

Comment: Might be you didn't posted your attempts whatever you have tried so far or any research you had done on it

Comment: Use  country_hub_id | category_id  as this will give you enough flexibility and normalization is easier with this.

Comment: yes exactly that's what I am doing . do you know how to implement it in laravel

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to remove the categories table. You can access the country_id and hub_id using the pivot method. Maybe this will help [Laravel's Documentation on Many to Many Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: no i need to associate category to hub_id,country_id